# Solve for $n$ in $2^n=8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponentiation

So, I was wondering if it is possible to solve for $n$ in $2^n=8$ (or any other question where $n$ is a power) using $9^{th}$ grade math. Please excuse my naïveté if this is extremely stupid/simple.

Thanks so much in advance! –– come to think of it: Is it possible at all?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 9th grade math? Have you learned about logarithms?

Comment: No... but would that do it?

Comment: My teacher won't introduce us to the subject :(

Comment: Trial and error is probably the only way you've learnt. $2^2 = 4$ is too small, and $2^4 = 16$ is too big. How about $2^3$?

Comment: Well, you can always use trial and error. The answer is a small, positive integer.

Comment: Just keep putting values of $n$ until you see that $n=3$ satisfies the equation. Use induction to prove that $2^{n} > 8 \ \forall \  n \geq4$.

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion Welcome to math.SE and thanks for asking! Just a tip for the future: try to make sure that you are very specific with your questions, and state what you know already. For example, you should make it clear that you know that $2^3=8$ and that your question is how you would come up with $n=3$ if you didn't know this already. This way, people's answers will tackle what you actually dont understand, and not just tell you what you already know. I look forward to seeing many more questions (and answers) from you.

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion. You'll likely be introduced to logarithms in a Algebra2 course and will work extensively with them in a Precalc class. Until then, this may quench your curiosity. Check out the first few videos. https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/logarithms-tutorial

Comment: In Ontario, logarithms aren't covered until grade 12 (Ontario has Canada's weakest high school math program :( ), so try to break down $8$ into its prime factorization and re-express it as a power of $2$. Assume that $$2^n=2^m\implies n=m$$

Answer (score 6):

Note that $8=2^3$. Compare it to $2^n$ and conclude that $n=3$.

Comment: This is really the answer. "Using logarithms" amounts to knowing this in the first place.

Comment: This is not AT ALL what I was saying. I obviously know that 2^3=8, but I simply picked a simple example. What if I had 124 = 4^n? I am asking if there is a way to solve that

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion Mathm0123 has described a method using logarithms.

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion To be fair, you really didn't ask that question, you asked a question that could be solved based on the fact that exponential functions are "one-to-one." Why bring out the heavy machinery if you don't have to?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to solve problems like this is using *logarithms*. If you have an equation 
$$10 ^x = y$$
where $y$ is any positive number, and you wish to find $x$, then the value of $x$ will be (by definition) $\log y$ (this is what the $\log$ button on your calculator is for).

For example, to solve 
$$10^x = 110$$
we calculate $$x=\log 110= 2.0413...$$
There is a simple way to solve any equation like this. If $a$ and $y$ are positive, then the solution of 
$$a^x = y$$
is 
$$x= \frac{\log y}{\log a}$$
So in your example, the answer would be $\frac{\log 8}{\log 2}=3$.

---

The theory of logarithms isn't too complicated, and logarithms were actually used as a way of multiplying large numbers before the invention of calculators (high school students would be given books of logarithms to use!). [Here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/logarithms-tutorial) is a good place to start learning about them.

However, at your level, the best way will be to use trial and error. For example, to solve $10^x=110$, we know that $10^2=100$ and $10^3=1000$, so $ x$ will be between $2$ and $3$. Similarly, we can show that $2<x<2.1$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is included in 9-th grade math, but here is a try to explain that $ 2^n, n \in \mathbb N $ tends to infinity as $n$ does so.

Obviously $n=3$ is a solution, since $2^3=8$. Now, if you try larger values of $n$ then $ 2^n$ becames larger and larger, since every time you multiply more times $2$ with itself. So, it is impossible to reach again $8$.

**Edit**(after Mathmo123 comment): Probably I misread the question, and I understood why is it unique. I apologize. If the question is " How we can solve this equation, i.e how to see that $n=3$ is a solution then we can work out a few values of $n$ since $8$ is small comparable to what we get raising $2^n$ for large n$. So, you try,

$n=1$: then, $2^1=2$

$n=2$: then, $ 2^2=4$

$n=3$: then, $\boxed{2^3=8}$

$n=4$: then, $2^4 =16>8$

$n=5$: then, $2^5= 32 > 8$

and so on...larger and larger.

For general exponential equations, we use logarithms as pointed out in the answer of Mathmo123.

Comment: I understood the question to be asking how one would come up with $n=3$ in the first place, perhaps in a less obvious example, and not how one could be sure that this was the only solution.

Comment: Sorry...I understood why this is unique. I didn't read the question carefully. But again one can say, to solve with trials since $8$ is quite small comparable to the value of $2^n$ as $n$ becames large.